# In Power BI, how can I update the analyze in Excel file to use the updated measure?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI file that I uploaded to the service.  I downloaded the analyze in an Excel file on my computer and it works fine.

However, I made a change to one of the measures, so the analyze in Excel is still showing data with the old measure.  How can I update the analyze in Excel file to use the latest measure without me having to download a new analyze in Excel file and rebuilding the pivot table?

Comment: What "measure"? What "analyze" (do you mean "analysis"?) What "service"? What is the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to republish the PBIX file to the service so that the new measure exists in the source that Excel connects to and then refresh the connection from Excel so that your spreadsheet gets updated.